# Swift: @objc(...) Attribute

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

In Apple-generated code (Core Data `NSManagedObject` subclasses, for example) I see this:

```
@objc(LPFile)
public class LPFile: NSManagedObject {
   ...
}
```

**My question is:** why is the `@objc` declaration done as above, instead of:

```
@objc public class LPFile: NSManagedObject {
   ...
}
```

or

```
@objcMembers public class LPFile: NSManagedObject {
   ...
}
```

What is special about the separate `@objc(identifier)` declaration? I can't seem to find documentation about it and googling just turns up the other two approaches. Thanks.

(NB: I'm aware class prefixes are not idiomatic Swift.)

Comment: I have a feeling that the fact that `className` returns `<module>.<name>` in one case (sans @objc(name)) and just `<name>` in the other plays some role (maybe for getting the `entityName` (?))...

Comment: It should still compile with just `@objc`. Does it not?

Comment: @Sweeper it should, but it wont work, because of the Objective-C runtime class name. I tried to explain it in my answer below (hope it's understandable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Alladinian is right. Suppose you have a framework `SharedSwift` with two classes:

```swift
@objc public class Foo: NSObject {}
@objc(Bar) public class Bar: NSObject {}
```

You can import this framework in the Objective-C code and use these two classes directly:

```c
@import SharedSwift;

Bar *b = [[Bar alloc] init];
Foo *f = [[Foo alloc] init];
```

But because Objective-C has a powerful runtime, you can do a lot of *magic*. One example is the [`NSClassFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395135-nsclassfromstring?language=objc) function:

```c
- (id _Nullable)instanceByName:(NSString * _Nonnull)name {
    Class c = NSClassFromString(name);
    return [[c alloc] init];
}

Foo *foo = [self instanceByName:@"Foo"];
Bar *bar = [self instanceByName:@"Bar"];
    
NSLog(@"%@ %@", foo, bar);
```

And the output is:

```
(null) <Bar: 0x6000015c4200>
```

What's the problem? `className` ...

```c
NSLog(@"%@ %@", [Foo className], [Bar className]);
```

... returns `SharedSwift.Foo` in one case (`@objc`) and `Bar` in another one (`@objc(Bar)`).

```
SharedSwift.Foo Bar
```

Let's add `AnotherSwift` framework to the mix with same classes and try to use `Foo` from both:

```c
@import SharedSwift;

NSLog(@"%@", [Foo className]); // SharedSwift.Foo
```

```c
@import AnotherSwift;

NSLog(@"%@", [Foo className]); // AnotherSwift.Foo
```

Works as expected. Try the same thing with the `Bar` class:

```c
@import SharedSwift;

NSLog(@"%@", [Bar className]); // Bar
```

```c
@import AnotherSwift;

NSLog(@"%@", [Bar className]); // Bar
```

`Bar` class is defined in both frameworks and which one will be used is undefined. See the error in the console when you try this:

```
Class Bar is implemented in both
.../Debug/SharedSwift.framework/Versions/A/SharedSwift (0x102b931c0) and
.../Debug/AnotherSwift.framework/Versions/A/AnotherSwift (0x102b841c0).
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

What's the reason for this?

As you can see, there's a difference between Objective-C code (`@import SharedSwift` & direct usage of `Foo`) & Objective-C runtime name (`NSClassFromString`, ...).

There's one namespace for everything in the Objective-C world. This is the reason for these two letters prefixes in the Apple frameworks (`NS`, `UI`, `CF`, ...) and three letters prefixes in the 3rd party code. Some 3rd party developers still do use two letters, but that's another story.

Swift has more namespaces - they're based on modules. It's a safe bet to include module name when the pure `@objc` attribute is used. To avoid possible ambiguity.

Check the [`NSEntityDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsentitydescription?language=objc) class for example - [`managedObjectClassName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsentitydescription/1425131-managedobjectclassname?language=objc) property:

> The name of the class that represents the receiver’s entity.

There's a lot of stuff around which leverages Objective-C runtime features, lot of stuff is based on just names (strings), ...

Comment: wait doesn't this then allow to melt swift classes to one objc class, apart from ambiguity risk and the "One of two will be used. Which one is undefined." ?

Comment: Excellent, thorough answer. As a decades-long Objective-C developer it's nice to see that people still exist who understand the foundations of the language.